# Scanner, Select File on Computer

Tags: java, file

Now, I read my `.txt` file by telling where is this file.
I want to change to I can select a file on my computer. How can I do that?

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("Sample.txt"));

while (file.hasNextLine()) {
    String input = file.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: You need a GUI for that . this is a console app

Comment: If you want to **select** a file from the file picker of your computer, you must use a GUI such as Swing or JavaFX. But I must say that you can prompt the user from the command line to enter the file path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a runnable you can try. Like @Verity has stipulated, use the [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html). Read the comments within the following code:

```
public class JFileChooserWithConsoleUse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A JFrame used here as a backbone for dialogs
        javax.swing.JFrame iFrame = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        iFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        iFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        iFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    
        String selectedFile = null;
        javax.swing.JFileChooser fc = new javax.swing.JFileChooser(new java.io.File("C:\\"));
        fc.setDialogTitle("Locate And Select A File To Read...");
        int userSelection = fc.showOpenDialog(iFrame);
    
        // The following code will not run until the 
        // FileChooser dialog window is closed.
        iFrame.dispose();   // Dispose of the JFrame.
        if (userSelection == 0) { 
            selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile().getPath();
        }

        // If no file was selected (dialog just closed) then 
        // get out of this method (which in this demo ultimately
        // ends (closes) the application.
        if (selectedFile == null) {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(iFrame, "No File Was Selected To Process!",
                                    "No File Selected!", javax.swing.JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            iFrame.dispose();   // Dispose of the JFrame.
            return;
        }
    
        // Read the selected file... 'Try With Resources' is 
        // used here so as to auto-close the reader. 
        try (java.util.Scanner file = new java.util.Scanner(new java.io.File(selectedFile))) {
            while (file.hasNextLine()) {
                String input = file.nextLine();
                // Display each read line in the Console Window.
                System.out.println(input);
            }
        }
        catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to use an [JFileChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).